# When is it safe to release memory I pass to DirectX?

Tags: c++, memory, directx

Many functions in the DirectX API take arrays as a pointer & a length (e.g. `RSSetViewports`). I can't see any documentation about how long the pointer needs to survive - just until the function returns or do I need to keep that array alive somehwere?

More generally, is there a lifetime convention for DirectX APIs, and is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

With DirectX 11, the pointers to structures are only needed within the call. Resource data is copied into the DirectX COM objects, and the reference counts manage the object lifetimes. Memory is allocated by the driver or the runtime and is a mix of GPU video memory, PCIe aperture memory, and system memory depending on the resource type. There's some additional complexity about how the memory is mapped in your virtual memory space, but in general you don't worry about it beyond keeping the COM objects alive.

XAudio2 requires you keep audio buffers alive until they are no longer used, where the older DirectSound API copied the audio data which was less efficient for the all CPU-based mixing model used by XAudio2.

For DirectX 12 it depends on the kind of memory you are talking about as more of the memory lifetime is managed explicitly by the application and you have to manage the GPU/CPU synchronization yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. One question; you say: "...beyond keeping the COM objects alive." If I pass a com_ptr-owned object into a directx function, do I need to keep that com_ptr alive? For example, `CreateDepthStencilView` takes a pointer to an `ID3D11Texture2D`: does the texture object need to outlive the depth stencil view?

Comment: Also, do you have a pointer to the relevant documentation? Not that I don't trust you, of course -- just for future reference.